# Different results for date() and gmdate()

Tags: php, date, time

I found something I can't really explain, maybe someone here can give me a hint.

I have the following test code, that prints 2 formatted timestamps, one for the 31.03.2013 and one for 31.03.2014, using `date()`and `gmdate()`:

```
<?php

function print_date($timestamp, $year) {
  // Add timezone offset for germany
  $timestamp += 3600;
  print "in $year\n";
  print "date:   " . date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timestamp) . "\n";
  print "gmdate: " . gmdate('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timestamp) . "\n";
  print "\n";
}

$end_2013 = 1364684400; // 31.03.2013
$end_2014 = 1396216800; // 31.03.2014
print_date($end_2013, '2013');
print_date($end_2014, '2014');

print "Default timezone: " . date_default_timezone_get() . "\n";
```

The result surprises me:

```
in 2013
date:   31.03.2013 01:00:00
gmdate: 31.03.2013 00:00:00

in 2014
date:   31.03.2014 01:00:00
gmdate: 30.03.2014 23:00:00

Default timezone: Europe/Berlin
```

Where does the difference in 2014 come from? My first thought is daylight savings time, but why doesn't that have an effect in 2013?
Why are there 2 hours difference in 2014 but only 1 hour difference in 2013?

Comment: What is your default timezone?

Comment: @Ramesh Europe/Berlin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Daylight savings for Berlin starts at

```
2013 Sunday, 31 March, 02:00 
2014 Sunday, 30 March, 02:00
```

Your specified **time** value for each date is 00:00 on that date, so for 2013 Sunday, 31 March it is **before** 2am, so no daylight savings; for 2014 it is after 2am on 30th March

Comment: ah, ok, you're right according to http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=37

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have already checked the docs. [gmdate](http://php.net/gmdate) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

change it

```
print "date:   " . date('d.m.Y', $timestamp) . "\n";
print "gmdate: " . gmdate('d.m.Y', $timestamp) . "\n";
```

with this

```
print "date:   " . date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timestamp) . "\n";
print "gmdate: " . gmdate('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timestamp) . "\n";
```

and you will find the difference.

Comment: But why do I have 2 hours difference in 2014 while I have only 1 hour difference in 2013?

Comment: Thanks already for your answer, I have updated my question with your input.

Answer (score 3):

`gmdate()` always Format in GMT/UTC date and time But `date()` always format according to the default time zone

Try this

```
 <?php
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
   echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it a DayLight Saving problem?

According to [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=37) , seem 2013-03-31 02:00:00 is changed to 03:00:00