# PHP Timezone incorrect When using time()

Tags: php, time, timezone, utc

I am using `time()` to record the current time in my PHP application.

I am based in the UK so we use UTC timezone. This means that in the summer/winter we switch from GMT timezone to BST (which is GMT +1). The problem was that, `time()` still uses GMT timezone which means it is 1 hour behind. How do I make it so it shows the BST time which is 1 hour ahead of GMT?

When I echo out the time, it is 1 hour behind.

**What I have Tried:**

- Adding the following pieces of code:

  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

  ini_set("date.timezone", "Europe/London");
- Re-Installing PHP 5.5 so the extensions storing timezones are updated.

Thanks

Comment: `time()` gives you back a unix timestamp which doesn't have a context of timezone. It's in UTC.

Comment: So do you know A solution?

Comment: Depends on what you're actually trying to do with the timestamp.

Comment: Log what time a user has saved an object in my database. Hence why I need the Time and not just the day/month/year.

Comment: In which case you shouldn't do anything with it. You should always store dates / times in UTC, then you can output them in any timezone very simply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP time() return a GMT/UTC Timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812170/does-php-time-return-a-gmt-utc-timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

Found my solution.

The problem is not with time() as that is just seconds past the date.

When coming to show the date, instead of using `gmdate()` instead use `date()`.

This will take into account any default timezones you set in your document/ini file.

Answer (score 0):

use `gmdate ()`

`string gmdate ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) and [Different results for date() and gmdate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219770/different-results-for-date-and-gmdate)

Comment: actually, i was already using gmdate and it wasnt working. As soon as i started using date(), it paid attention to my timezone configs